# Why Shellshock works in useragent string?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, apache, shellshock

I was wondering why Shellshock works when put in the useragent.

Based on what I could find it is because a web server (e.g Apache) uses the useragent string in its internal working.

1. Why would a webserver care about the useragent? AFAIK decisions based on useragent are made in the application with the programmer building the logic like if (mobile) : show mobile version etc.
2. Why would the webserver use an Environment Variable to handle this?! couldn't this be done through regular variable-value form with enough sanitization on  the input? As far as I know env-vars are not bash exclusive, they are defined in a system wide scope. I still don't get the connection!

Comment: The [webservers are the ones using the user agents to make decisions](http://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/).  Not the client.  Terrible programming is probably the answer to number 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
(Edited, I got it wrong first time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A webserver could use the contents of the [`User-Agent`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) header for [logging purposes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#example), to control access ("deny all bots") or return alternative responses ("mobile-friendly pages"). The validity of a header value depends on the application, it is not possible to write on rule that works with everything.

Consider the [`Cookie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) header. One site could purely use it to store a session identifier such as `sessionid=01234567890abcdef`. A different site might choose to store locales, such as `lang=nl-NL`. You could apply a character blacklist, but then someone might exploit a bug in your application which results in `lang=--help` being treated as an [command-line option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt).

For [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) programs, web browsers will usually invoke the script and pass headers via environment variables such that [the script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Syntax) can use this information as well. This is not limited to the `User-Agent` header, the values of `Cookie` might be more interesting for the script. The "form input" as you describe is [different](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) from the headers. Headers come before the message body.

Now about the Bash bug that leads to the "Shellshock" security issue, all you need is control over at least one environment variable. As you can see, direct CGI access on a webserver is one example where that condition is satisfied. You could also be affected when the program (PHP, Cgit, ...) invokes the shell, directly (via a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script)) or indirectly (via a [shell command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)).

Comment: That was convincing. Would you please post some references which you have used to make this conclusion?

Comment: @Sam Done, let me know if anything if you still have any questions.